# How to use autowiring in classes where the method can be called for outside the spring context

Tags: java, spring

Converting my web-application to Spring. Autowiring is successful in cases where it is initiated in Spring context but fails in other situations, as it should.

I have a `MangaBean` which has a property named `genre`. Genre's value should be one from the excepted set of genres. I have **placed the validations in the bean itself**. Something like this:

```
    @Component
public class MangaBean{
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String isbn;
    private String genre;

    //getters

    public void setTitle(String title){
        //validations
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre){
        boolean result=MangaUtil.verifyGenre(genre);
        if(result){
            this.genre=genre;
        }else{
            this.genre=null;
        }
    }
}
```

The util calls the method that fetches set of genres from the table and validates the provided genre.

```
@Component
public class MangaUtil{
    @Autowired
    MangaDao mDao;

    public static boolean verifyGenre(String genre){
        List<String> genres=mDao.getGenresList();   //null pointer exception 
            //do validations
    }
}
```

`MangaDao` contains an autowired `NamedParameterJDBCTemplate` which fetches genres from DB.

Code for MangaDao:

```
@Repository
public class MangaDao{
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

    public List<String> getGenresList(){
        String query="select genres from manga_table";
        Map<String,String> paramMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
        return template.queryForList(query, paramMap, String.class);
    }
}
```

In the above arrangement, the call to MangaUtil works fine when I autowire MangaUtil as well. Example:

```
@Component
public class MangaBean{
    @Autowired
    MangaUtil mangaUtil;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String isbn;
    private String genre;

    //getters

    public void setTitle(String title){
        //validations
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre){
        boolean result=mangaUtil.verifyGenre(genre);
        if(result){
            this.genre=genre;
        }else{
            this.genre=null;
        }
    }
}
```

But if I use autowiring inside a bean, the autowire would fail in cases I instantiate the bean myself like `MangaBean mb=new MangaBean()`. Please advice for a situation like this. **I want to call the validator method from my bean without any autowiring in bean itself. Is it possible?**. If not, is there any way I can store a list of genres and use it in the bean to validate my data. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

By default autowiring works only for Spring managed beans i.e. that are created by Spring. To make it work for beans instantiated with e.g. `new` see the Spring docs:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable

You need to use @Configurable annotation and configure AspectJ as per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a real answer to your problem. But I wonder how you were able to compile this code:

```
@Component
public class MangaUtil(){ // <<< parentheses not allowed here
    @Autowired
    MangaDao mDao;

    public static boolean verifyGenre(String genre){
        List<String> genres=mDao.getGenresList();   // <<< you are referencing a non static attribute from a static method
    }
}
```